# How to move video to the other position on the site and keep it playing? (example given)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, iframe

Please see this site: (works for sure in Firefox): http://www.cnn.com/2016/02/01/politics/iowa-caucuses-2016-highlights/index.html

There's a video and after you scroll the page down it gets smaller and goes to the right sidebar and keeps playing from the exact minute it was playing before.

I see that this video is not an iframe. I need to do such thing for Vimeo's iframe video. How can this be achieved?

I'm trying to take a HTML for the video and then append it but it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Can only be done by changing position of existing element. Append removes it from DOM which will cancel video playing. Examine how they do it in the live html

Comment: Yeah, I can see how it's done by changing the position property. Thought I could do more about it but this also should do the trick. Thanks for the info.